# Update record based on the other record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this, I want to update the value of `AttemptNumber` column based on record with the value based on the previous record.

| txnId | UserId | Retry | AttemptNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | False | 0 |
| 2 | 12 | True | 1 |
| 3 | 12 | True | 2 |
| 4 | 12 | False | 0 |
| 5 | 12 | True | 1 |
| 6 | 12 | True | 2 |
| 7 | 12 | False | 0 |

Whenever I encounter `Retry` value as 'False', then I want to keep the `AttemptNumber` as `0`.

Whenever I encounter `Retry` value as 'True', then I want to increment the value in the `AttemptNumber`.
Currently I don't have the column AttemptNumber in the table, I will create the column and update the values based on the value present in 'Retry'.

Comment: Has your recorded any order?

Comment: @ArashGhazi Can you elaborate a bit, I didn't understand.

Comment: @DaleK I tried creating the 'Attemptnumber' column with all NULL values first, after that I have updated the 'Attemptnumber' column with '0' whenever I saw a 'False' in the retry. I am unable to figure out how to update the 'Attemptnumber' whenever I encounter 'True' consecutively.

Comment: if you want to find the previous records, the records must have an order in your table

Comment: @ArashGhazi the records are ordered by UserId

Comment: I recommend researching gaps-and-islands SQL.

Comment: what is the primary key in the table?

Comment: @ArashGhazi Its txnId

Comment: the Primary key can't  be repeated

Comment: @ArashGhazi Sorry Its txnId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define groups, based on the values in the `Retry` column and number the rows appropriately:

Test data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 12, 'False', 0),
   (2, 12, 'True',  0),
   (3, 12, 'True',  0),
   (4, 12, 'False', 0),
   (5, 12, 'True',  0),
   (6, 12, 'True',  0),
   (7, 12, 'False', 0)
) v (TxnId, UserId, Retry, AttemptNumber)
```

Statement:

```
; WITH UpdateCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      TxnId, UserId, Retry, AttemptNumber,
      ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, GroupId ORDER BY TxnId) - 1 AS NewAttemptNumber
   FROM (
      SELECT 
         *,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Retry = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY TxnId) AS GroupId
      FROM Data
   ) t  
)
UPDATE UpdateCTE
SET AttemptNumber = NewAttemptNumber
```

Result:

| TxnId | UserId | Retry | AttemptNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | False | 0 |
| 2 | 12 | True | 1 |
| 3 | 12 | True | 2 |
| 4 | 12 | False | 0 |
| 5 | 12 | True | 1 |
| 6 | 12 | True | 2 |
| 7 | 12 | False | 0 |

Comment: In this set it won't work correctly: ``(1,12,'False',0),
(2,12,'True',0),
(3,12,'False',0),
(4,13,'False',0),
(5,13,'True',0),
(6,12,'True',0),
(7,12,'True',0)``

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad, thanks, the comment is correct. The windowed `SUM` and `ROW_NUMBER` need a correct `PARTITION BY` clause. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code

```sql
declare @x int=0
update t1 set
[AttemptNumber]=iif(t1.Retry=1,@x,0),
@x=iif(t1.Retry=1,(@x + 1),0)
from t1
```

Comment: Nice query Arash

Comment: thanks, but it can have problems in some situations

Comment: Oh yes for different useId it won't work